# How to assign a specific job to each thread for matrix addition in openmp

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

I am trying to create a matrix addition program to practice with OpenMP. I have N^2 processors/threads and need to assign each thread such that it computes one entry of the resultant matrix. For example, if I have two matrices A and B of size NxN, then each thread should compute one entry of the resultant matrix C. Upon reading some of the beginner tutorials in OpenMp it seems that the #pragma omp parallel for directive divides the tasks equally among the total number of threads specified. But in the code below only 3 threads are active, and not 9 as I want.

The code I have is as follows:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include "omp.h"



void  main() {

  // omp_set_num_threads(NUM_THREADS);
  int i, k;
  int N=3;

  int A[3][3] = { {1, 2, 3},{ 5, 6, 7}, {8,9,10} };
  int B[3][3] =  { {1, 2, 3},{ 5, 6, 7}, {8,9,10} };
  int C[3][3] ;

  omp_set_dynamic(0);
   omp_set_num_threads(9);
   // printf("Num of threads %i \n", omp_get_max_threads());

#pragma omp parallel for private(i,k) shared(A, B, C, N)

  for (i = 0; i< N; i++) {
    for (k=0; k< N;k++){

           int j = omp_get_thread_num();

       C[i][k] = A[i][k] +  B[i][k] ;


              printf("I m thread %d computing A[%d][%d] and B[%d][%d] = %d \n ", j, i,k, i,k, C[i][k]);

  }
  }


  int n, m;
  for (n=0; n<3; n++) {
    for ( m=0;m<3;m++){
      printf("C[%d][%d] = %d \n",n,m, C[n][m]);   

 }


}

}
```

And the output I am getting is:

```
I m thread 0 computing A[0][0] and B[0][0] = 2 
 I m thread 1 computing A[1][0] and B[1][0] = 10 
 I m thread 1 computing A[1][1] and B[1][1] = 12 
 I m thread 1 computing A[1][2] and B[1][2] = 14 
 I m thread 0 computing A[0][1] and B[0][1] = 4 
 I m thread 0 computing A[0][2] and B[0][2] = 6 
 I m thread 2 computing A[2][0] and B[2][0] = 16 
 I m thread 2 computing A[2][1] and B[2][1] = 18 
 I m thread 2 computing A[2][2] and B[2][2] = 20 
 C[0][0] = 2 
C[0][1] = 4 
C[0][2] = 6 
C[1][0] = 10 
C[1][1] = 12 
C[1][2] = 14 
C[2][0] = 16 
C[2][1] = 18 
C[2][2] = 20
```

What I want though is that each of the nine threads compute one entry of the matrix C. Could anyone please help regarding this. I am new to C and OpenMP both. I am also confused regarding the exact function of private variables in the private clause. For example, if I specify 'i' and 'k' as private, then does that mean that each of the thread will have a copy of 'i' and 'k' and may therefore run their own iteration of the loop? but that doesn't make sense since in the above output thread 0 is computing all the row 0 values, and thread 1 all the row 1 values. How is this happening on its own without any specific directive? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `#pragma omp parallel for` on outer for loop, it is applied only on the outer loop, which only iterates 3 times (`N = 3`), so you only need 3 threads.

If you want to use 9 threads, you should collapse the 2d array to 1d, using a single index, let's call it `p`:

```
#pragma omp parallel for private(i, k, p) shared(A, B, C, N)
for (p = 0; p < N * N; p++) {
    i = p / N;
    k = p % N;
    C[i][k] = A[i][k] + B[i][k];
}
```

---

As stated on George's answer and Timothy's comment, you can also use OpenMP's `collapse(2)` keyword to achieve the same thing.

Comment: You could also use the `collapse(2)` keyword and argument to the pragma statement.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers chrk and Timothy, those two methods work perfectly! Also clarified a great deal about how the parallelism is applied to the outer loop alone.

Answer (score 3):

Another way ,if you want to retain the 2 loops ,besides 'chrk' answer ,is to use:

```
#pragma omp parallel for private(i,k) shared(A, B, C, N) collapse(2)
```

Like this , you will have parallel execution in both loops.
Because , right now , you have only parallel execution in the outer loop.
That's why you see that for example thread 1 calculates all the row 1 values.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer George, I tried both methods, and they both work great. I was wondering suppose if I have a fixed number of threads less than 9 (N^2), and I want each of those threads to calculate one row of the matrix C, then it should work with my above code without the collapse clause, right? But perhaps it might not work with number of threads = 5 ?

Comment: @QPTR, it should work with any number of threads. It could just happen that they don't get the same amount of work or some of them might idle (i.e. get no work at all).

Comment: @QPTR: Hristo Iliev answered your question.